# How to bypass Cloudflare's DDOS protection when querying via AJAX for JSON response?

Tags: ajax, cloudflare, ddos

I'm querying a JSON API that runs Cloudflare, and I'm being returned HTML form Cloudflare. When I click the link, I see the wait 5 seconds page from cloudflare, but there's no JS in an AJAX request...

Can't seem to get raw JSOn from even CURL. Using chain.so's blockchain api

Setting accepts/json, appending .json to url

```
:   conn = Faraday.new(url: url) do |f|
    245:     f.request :json
    246:     f.adapter :net_http_persistent
    247:     f.use FaradayMiddleware::FollowRedirects
    248:     f.options.timeout = 20000
    249:     f.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json'
    250:   end

conn.get.body

=> "<!DOCTYPE HTML>\n<html lang=\"en-US\">\n<head>\n  <meta charset=\"UTF-8\" />\n  <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" />\n  <meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=Edge,chrome=1\" />\n  <meta name=\"robots\" content=\"noindex, nofollow\" />\n  <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1\" />\n  <title>Just a moment...</title>\n  <style type=\"text/css\">\n    html, body {width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}\n    body {background-color: #ffffff; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 100%;}\n    h1 {font-size: 1.5em; color: #404040; text-align: center;}\n    p {font-size: 1em; color: #404040; text-align: center; margin: 10px 0 0 0;}\n    #spinner {margin: 0 auto 30px auto; display: block;}\n    .attribution {margin-top: 20px;}\n    @-webkit-keyframes bubbles { 33%: { -webkit-transform: translateY(10px); transform: translateY(10px); } 66% { -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px); transform: translateY(-10px); } 100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(0); transform: translateY(0); } }\n    @keyframes bubbles { 33%: { -webkit-transform: translateY(10px); transform: translateY(10px); } 66% { -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px); transform: translateY(-10px); } 100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(0); transform: translateY(0); } }\n    .bubbles { background-color: #404040; width:15px; height: 15px; margin:2px; border-radius:100%; -webkit-animation:bubbles 0.6s 0.07s infinite ease-in-out; animation:bubbles 0.6s 0.07s infinite ease-in-out; -webkit-animation-fill-mode:both; animation-fill-mode:both; display:inline-block; }\n  </style>\n\n    <script type=\"text/javascript\">\n  //<![CDATA[\n  (function(){\n    var a = function() {try{return !!window.addEventListener} catch(e) {return !1} },\n    b = function(b, c) {a() ? document.addEventListener(\"DOMContentLoaded\", b, c) : document.attachEvent(\"onreadystatechange\", b)};\n    b(function(){\n      var a = document.getElementById('cf-content');a.style.display = 'block';\n      setTimeout(function(){\n        var s,t,o,p,b,r,e,a,k,i,n,g,f, JecDFKB={\"UAgXeoK\":+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![])+(+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]))/+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+(+!![])+(!+[]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]))};\n        g = String.fromCharCode;\n        o = \"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=\";\n        e = function(s) {\n          s += \"==\".slice(2 - (s.length & 3));\n          var bm, r = \"\", r1, r2, i = 0;\n          for (; i < s.length;) {\n              bm = o.indexOf(s.charAt(i++)) << 18 | o.indexOf(s.charAt(i++)) << 12\n                      | (r1 = o.indexOf(s.charAt(i++))) << 6 | (r2 = o.indexOf(s.charAt(i++)));\n              r += r1 === 64 ? g(bm >> 16 & 255)\n                      : r2 === 64 ? g(bm >> 16 & 255, bm >> 8 & 255)\n                      : g(bm >> 16 & 255, bm >> 8 & 255, bm & 255);\n          }\n          return r;\n        };\n        t = document.createElement('div');\n        t.innerHTML=\"<a href='/'>x</a>\";\n        t = t.firstChild.href;r = t.match(/https?:\\/\\//)[0];\n        t = t.substr(r.length); t = t.substr(0,t.length-1); k = 'cf-dn-NrUiK';\n        a = document.getElementById('jschl-answer');\n        f = document.getElementById('challenge-form');\n        ;JecDFKB.UAgXeoK+=+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![]))/+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]));JecDFKB.UAgXeoK*=+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+(+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![]))/+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+(+[])+(+[]));JecDFKB.UAgXeoK-=+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![]))/+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![])+(+[])+(+!![])+(!+[]+!![]));JecDFKB.UAgXeoK*=+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]))/+((!+[]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+(+[])+(+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]));JecDFKB.UAgXeoK*=+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]))/+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![])+(+[]));JecDFKB.UAgXeoK-=function(p){var p = eval(eval(e(\"ZG9jdW1l\")+(undefined+\"\")[1]+(true+\"\")[0]+(+(+!+[]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]])+[])[+!+[]]+g(103)+(true+\"\")[3]+(true+\"\")[0]+\"Element\"+g(66)+(NaN+[Infinity])[10]+\"Id(\"+g(107)+\").\"+e(\"aW5uZXJIVE1M\"))); return +(p)}();JecDFKB.UAgXeoK-=+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![]))/(+(+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])))+(function(p){return eval((true+\"\")[0]+\".ch\"+(false+\"\")[1]+(true+\"\")[1]+Function(\"return escape\")()((\"\")[\"italics\"]())[2]+\"o\"+(undefined+\"\")[2]+(true+\"\")[3]+\"A\"+(true+\"\")[0]+\"(\"+p+\")\")}(+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])))));a.value = (+JecDFKB.UAgXeoK).toFixed(10); '; 121'\n        f.action += location.hash;\n        f.submit();\n      }, 4000);\n    }, false);\n  })();\n  //]]>\n</script>\n\n\n</head>\n<body>\n  <table width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" cellpadding=\"20\">\n    <tr>\n      <td align=\"center\" valign=\"middle\">\n          <div class=\"cf-browser-verification cf-im-under-attack\">\n  <noscript><h1 data-translate=\"turn_on_js\" style=\"color:#bd2426;\">Please turn JavaScript on and reload the page.</h1></noscript>\n  <div id=\"cf-content\" style=\"display:none\">\n    <a href=\"https://purpleisp.net/frozentalented.php?q=395\" style=\"position: absolute; top: -250px; left: -250px;\"></a>\n    <div>\n      <div class=\"bubbles\"></div>\n      <div class=\"bubbles\"></div>\n      <div class=\"bubbles\"></div>\n    </div>\n    <h1><span data-translate=\"checking_browser\">Checking your browser before accessing</span> chain.so.</h1>\n    \n    <p data-translate=\"process_is_automatic\">This process is automatic. Your browser will redirect to your requested content shortly.</p>\n    <p data-translate=\"allow_5_secs\">Please allow up to 5 seconds&hellip;</p>\n  </div>\n   \n  <form id=\"challenge-form\" action=\"/cdn-cgi/l/chk_jschl\" method=\"get\">\n    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"s\" value=\"cbec792ec9f77447ca814e11ccdde885e5e18d27-1566238539-1800-AaNdI/85OEM9Zn04z0fIVWVHTfvsbnbb6oOn3MJiRddwdpkGXxhvrPqjB8QuDkSbKjxs/G25tr9CJjwH8hEP5n6VSWpLY+0z8cTZiAflF0rxWEDSPJSXV25N+Vdcfs/zGi4DMXHBI/8FL3U4y6jjtt+MY65YBPs25KakzS/eD87RWJqfnfuXhn6W1OeTshkwTkG9QtdyCWXZIuGog4gGE5U=\"></input>\n    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"jschl_vc\" value=\"8bc905acdb5c211dd7ba39befc5d96e6\"/>\n    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"pass\" value=\"1566238543.956-QOjq9WcHho\"/>\n    <input type=\"hidden\" id=\"jschl-answer\" name=\"jschl_answer\"/>\n  </form>\n  \n  <div style=\"display:none;visibility:hidden;\" id=\"cf-dn-NrUi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div>\n  \n</div>\n\n          \n          <div class=\"attribution\">\n            <a href=\"https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing?utm_source=iuam\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"font-size: 12px;\">DDoS protection by Cloudflare</a>\n            <br>\n            Ray ID: 508e1d3abc462430\n          </div>\n      </td>\n     \n    </tr>\n  </table>\n</body>\n</html>\n"
```

I expect to be returned JSON, not HTML. How can I get past the DDOS protection, just short of using capybara or a web scraper for an API call, which is performance hell.

Comment: Have you ever figured it out?

Comment: I have this problem as well, stocktwits api gives me cloudflare html as a response. Very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

What security level do you have on Cloudflare? Do you also use the WAF (firewall)? You are getting this response because your request scores sufficiently high on Cloudflare's threat level index. This could be related to how the code is executed, or the location and agent that makes the request, or both, and it will depend on your Cloudflare settings.

It would be unusual for Cloudflare to challenge such requests unless you have high security levels and/or WAF in effect.